# How to multiply a series of matrices together?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a numpy array of matrices which i am trying to multiply together in the form A * B * C * D where A is the first matrix, B is the second and so on. I have tried this code:

```
matrix = matrices[0]
for m in matrices[1:]:
    matrix = np.matmul(matrix, m)
```

However I believe this multiplication is wrong as i get incorrect output variables, and I have triple checked the rest of my code so I believe this is the issue. How can I multiply all the matrices in this array together? Also the array length will vary depending on the input file, thus i cant use an A * B * C approach.

Comment: if the arrays are different lengths, then what are you accomplishing exactly? Also have you tried `np.dot(a, b)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman How do you know it's a zero matrix? There is a list of matrices and he sets matrix equal to the first element

Comment: Are you sure that the axis you are iterating through is the correct axis?

Comment: Can you add this line `print(m.shape)` in the loop and provide the output?

Comment: Look at `np.linalg.multi_dot`.  It's of most value if the arrays differ in size, and the order of evaluation can change speed.  But since your arrays all have the same size, the order shouldn't matter.  Still it might be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for multiply a series of matrices together should work. Here is an example using your method with some simple matrices.

```
import numpy as np

matrices = []
matrices.append(np.eye(3,dtype=float))
matrices.append(np.matrix('1.0,2.0,3.0;4.0,5.0,6.0;7.0,8.0,8.0'))
matrices.append(np.eye(3,dtype=float))
matrices.append(np.linalg.inv(np.matrix('1.0,2.0,3.0;4.0,5.0,6.0;7.0,8.0,8.0')))

matrix = matrices[0]
for m in matrices[1:]:
    matrix = np.matmul(matrix, m)
print(matrix)

directmul = np.matmul(matrices[1],matrices[3])
print(np.subtract(matrix,directmul))
```

Your problem is somewhere else: maybe how you are filling the list of matrices, or how are you filling the matrices. Have you tried `unit testing` on your code? Have you give a try to the python debugger?